# Which of the following sentences sounds most formal?

Tags: tenses, formality

1 - The president travels to Belo Horizonte tomorrow.
2 The president is going to travel to Belo Horizonte tomorrow.
3 The president is traveling to Belo Horizonte tomorrow.
4 The president will travel to Belo Horizonte tomorrow.

Comment: #1 is more dated / poetic / oratorical than "formal". And #2 is a fairly relaxed colloquial usage. #3 is still *slightly* "informal" by comparison with #4 (which is neither formal nor informal - it's just "normal" English).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would only add that, grammatically, they are identical: in each case the verb is intransitive, meaning it would still make sense as "The president travels' "The president will travel." etc.